# One object for all wcf customers

Tags: c#, wcf, dictionary

I have a `wcf` service that I keep him `Dictionary`.

```
private Dictionary<string, string> MyDic= new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Any call I done the dictionary cleared.

I want this object to be recognized in all of the calls to all the customers as **one object**.

Here the function that called from the client when I use the above object.

```
    public void AddToList(string string1, string string2)
    {
        MyDic[string1] = string2;
    }
```

There is a way to do this?

Comment: You want to use a `static` variable: `private static Dictionary<string,string> MyDic = new Dictionary<string,string>();`

Comment: You could also use an instance property and use the WCF SingleInstance context mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to instanziate the service as a single Instance:

```
 [ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class ConfigurationService : IConfigurationService
```